# Create Custom View In iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

How Can I Create Custom View Like This ?
like this

[image]

Anyone Have Tutorials to make view like left hand side view?

Comment: Two possible way. It could be a custom `UITableViewCell`, which is native. Or it is made using HTML5. What have you tried so far? You want answers, you have to show effort.

Comment: how can i create it  custom UITableViewCell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one on the left hand side isn't quite distinguishable from UITableView. All you need is to put it on storyboard and play with its properties - like you can set row height from storyboard itself. To customize the titles like 'Browse Gifts', 'BirthDays' etc. - refer to delegate method tableView:viewForHeaderInSection under [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Then there is [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1) excellent tutorial about how to make horizontal scrolling of rows possible in your table view.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good tutorial -> http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view
Or just make a google search.

You need to subclass UIView and make your own drawing using other UIView subclasses (UILabel, UIImageView, ...) or your own CoreGraphics.

For your example you can make one UIView for the exterior rectangle and another for the interior. You can use view.layer border (you will need CG). The other things are simply UILabel's and UIImageView's.

Comment: do you know any template projects that make custom view like this ? :D

Comment: There is no template available.  No one gives away beautiful UIView.

Comment: I don't know any template for this. But truly you just need to subclass the UIView and make your subviews there.